# jquery-ui progressbar not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a simple progress bar to my application in rails using jquery-ui. I'm following this example:  http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

I create the div

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

and in my JS I have

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 37
  });
});
```

But nothing happens to the div in the html - it remains empty and unstyled(ie no additional CSS is applied to it).

I have checked that I have jquery-ui included in my application - in particular, I have made certain the jquery-ui css file is included.

However, I am willing to bet the problem has something to do with jquery-ui not working properly in my app, because I was having another issue with it and the tooltip function, which I asked about over here: [positioning jQuery tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278630/positioning-jquery-tooltip)

This is driving me nuts, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "not showing" isn't enough to help you. Does the element exist in the DOM? Is the display set to none? Is there a javascript error?

Comment: Can you post the code for your progress bar div?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now.

It seems like the referenced libaries in the example do not work.
The error i get from the "Firefox - Developer Tools - Browser Console" is:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

(I tested on Firefox 32.0.3 and IE 11)

If you just copy the example html/jquery source from "http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/" to a local file (lets call it: "testJqueryProgressBar.html") and double click it, you will see no progress bar!

Source of "testJqueryProgressBar.html":

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        $(function() 
        {
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: 37 });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Therefore i checked the links in the header of the example and all reference something.
So the links are valid!

I even tried to reference the jquery libs from another provider, f.e. : https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=de#jquery-ui.
Same problem!

Then i went to http://jqueryui.com/download/ 
Selected Version : 1.11.1 (Stable, for jQuery1.6+) 
Selected a different UI theme at the bottom

Downloaded the zip and referenced these unziped jquery sources in my local example testJqueryProgressBar.html and it worked.