# How to position jQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tooltip" title="Name">
<input type="text">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now how i position jQuery tooltip ?
[Tooltip](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position)

From API i am trying my best to do so ! but i am undone.
I am changing only HTML and Js file . I am not doing any changes in CSS. Is that okay?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? The positioning is relative to what was clicked on to trigger the tooltip. Try no positioning. Does tooltip show up? Okay, now change the `my` and see what happens. Without code and what is happening versus what you want to happen, it is hard to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [positioning jQuery tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278630/positioning-jquery-tooltip)

Comment: i made some change in my post !